# Change "this" to a variable name within name space

Tags: javascript, class, namespaces, this

I am doing a project that need to be done by using name space. I have some troubble getting it to work when I need to change "this" to an actually 
variable name.

Thus.

I created a name space $work.
Then a class named $work.Guess (then I renamed it to "game")
Then a method named point. (the method fires from onclick on a button)

I have tried to change "this" to something else.. In my mind it SHOULD be game.point, but that did not work. So I then tried with "var point". Neither of them worked with the onclick event from the button. Then I have tried to reach the method with every name I could think would work instead of "this". Failed.

Here is a sample code.

```js
var $work = {};
$work.Guess = function() {

  this.point = function() {
    alert('found' + " " + 'point');
  }

}

var game = new $work.Guess;
```

```html
<form name="foo">
  <h2>Check scores</h2>
  <input type="button" value="Check points" onclick='game.point();' />
  <br />
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem here? You only have a paragraph telling us what you tried, but not really the problem. *"I have tried to change "this" to something else"* - why? and how? We don't see that in the code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var game = new $work.Guess()` ?

Comment: The snippet is working? I don't see the problem/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right wanting to get rid of the `this` here. Adding instance methods this way to an object is wasteful, as it creates a new copy of the function for each object. In Javascript, "class method inheritance" (as it's classically called) is done through the prototype:

```
$work.Guess = function () { };
$work.Guess.prototype.point = function () {
    alert('found point');
};

var game = new $work.Guess();
game.point();
```

And I'd be amiss not to also point to the nicer [ES6 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) here.

Comment: I do like this solution better.  I was going to post it, but I was  AFK for a little bit.  Most of the time (if not all of the time) methods will belong in the prototype, I've found.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var $work = {};
$work.Guess = {
    point: function() {
        alert('found' + " " + 'point');
    }
};

var game = $work.Guess;
```

**Update:**

No idea what the downvotes are for.  Either way, the above works just fine.

```
<form name="foo">
  <h2>Check scores</h2>
  <input type="button" value="Check points" onclick='game.point();' />
  <br />
</form>
```

Comment: Your solution is basically the OP snippet, just with a different syntax.

Comment: The original is working just fine as well. `game` will have a public method `.point()`, because that's added inside the constructor.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, OP's question was how to change the code to something that doesn't use `this`, and that's exactly what you did.  Upvote from me.

Comment: @Jamen Of course, now you cannot have multiple instances of `Guess` anymore with this revised code, which is quite a regression on the original...

Comment: @deceze That's a good point.  I guess you could copy it with `Object.assign`.

Comment: @Jamen ...which you hopefully wouldn't do in practice. Cloning an object instead of using a constructor function is... rather unidiomatic at best. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know it is working. The reson why I dont want to use " this" is that I will make a bit more complicated later. I am really not so sure about either name space or the use of "this".

Comment: @deceze i think you're grasping for straws.   cloning an object vs using a constructor is probably one of the most used practices in all of javascript heh.

Comment: @Jonathon Cloning an instance and instantiating a new instance are two entirely different operations with different purposes. I'd hope nobody is equating these two as serious alternatives...!?

Comment: @deceze to your point - of course i realize they are different operations =)    with that being said, i think i'll stop here though.   it feels like its turning into more of an argument than anything helpful to the OP's original question.